# which event should i handle to adjust the size of controls on winform?

Tags: .net, winforms, resize

when my form is shown, i want to adjust the height of certain control, i do this in the Shown Event handler, it doesn't work, so which event should i handle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer is, use the [Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.layout.aspx) event. But with .NET 2.0 and up you really have much better tools at your disposal. I would look into the Anchor property, the Dock property, the TableLayoutPanel, FlowLayoutPanel, etc.

It's very rare that you should need to manually layout controls unless you're implementing a custom layout.